# reset setInterval in javascript

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I have just made a version of the "10 PRINT" to try to develop my JS skills.

In the end i thought it would be nice to add some sliders and let the viewers adjust some of the parameters to see what effect they have.

You can see what i came up with here: [10PRINT, by Boguz, on GitHub](https://boguz.github.io/10PRINT/)

One of the sliders i wanted to add changes the speed of the animation, but i can get it to work.

To trigger the animation i am using a setInterval like this:

```
setInterval(function(speed){
    draw();
}, speed);
```

The variable speed is initialized when the document loads

```
let speed = 50;
```

and then i am trying to update it (when the viewer moves the slider) like this:

```
const speedControl = document.querySelector("#speed-slider");
speedControl.oninput = function() {
    let speedVal = speedControl.value;
    speed = Number(speedVal);
    resetDraw();
}
```

When i log the speed variable i get the right values in the console, but somehow it is not having the desired effect.

If you need to see some more code, please ask me, or take a look at the [GitHub Repository](https://github.com/boguz/10PRINT).

Any help is very welcome.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your script store the `setInterval` value so you can clear it.

```
// SET INTERVAL
let drawInterval = setInterval(function(){
        draw();
}, speed);
```

then in your `resetDraw` clear the interval and re set it (*it will now use the new `speed`*)

```
function resetDraw() {
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);   
    xpos = 0;
    ypos = 0;
    draw();
    clearInterval(drawInterval);
    drawInterval = setInterval(draw, speed);
}
```

---

You could also completely remove the initial `setInterval` and just call the `resetDraw` once to start.

Comment: Or rather `let drawInterval = setInterval(draw, speed);` - since `draw` is already a *`function`*

Answer (score 1):

Clear your old one first, then make a new one

```
function makeInterval(speed) {
    const intervalId = setInterval(function(){
        draw();
    }, speed);
    return intervalId;
}


let intervalId = makeInterval(speed);

...oninput = function() {
    clearInterval(intervalId);
    let speedVal = speedControl.value;
    speed = Number(speedVal);
    intervalId = makeInterval(speedVal);
}
```

The interval time passed to `setInterval` can't be live updated, it's baked in to the call when you make it.